# Does someone knows how calculate scalar product of two gradients and put the result in terms of nabla operator? .

Tags: vector-analysis

$(\vec\nabla{\gamma})\cdot(\vec\nabla{\gamma})$ = ?

Does someone knows how calculate scalar product of two gradients and put the result in terms of nabla operator using indicial notation? .

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too ambiguous, as of now, the best answer I can give you is $\left( \vec{\nabla} \gamma \right) \cdot \left( \vec{\nabla} \gamma \right) = \left \| \vec{\nabla} \gamma \right \|^2$.
Can you specify your question ?

Comment: Thanks for you response.I would like the answer in indicial notation